# Docker buildx with different base images

Tags: docker, tegra, buildx

I would like to build images for the `amd64` and Nvidia `l4t` platforms. Right now I pass the base image names `amd64/debian:buster-slim` and `nvcr.io/nvidia/l4t-base:r32.6.1` into my `Dockerfile`. I then run a shell script that calls `docker build` twice with different base image names as `--build-arg`.

I've read about `docker buildx` which seems quite interesting. However I haven't found how I can define different base images for my target platforms.

Is this possible?

Comment: I assume there is a way to rename the images using `docker tag`, `docker rmi` before starting buildx, but this is an awkward preprocessing step which I assume is not neccessary.